# printing a page in javascript not following the css

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I am printing a div in a javascript and i was putting a css within it, why it doesn't follow my css? anything i put in my css was something nothing or it doesn't have an effect to arrange my print section. Can anyone teach me how to arrange the printing page in a javascript code with css to arrange my print?.

how do i apply my css in this situation,

Here is my code:

```js
function printDiv() {
  var divToPrint = document.getElementById('printme');
  var htmlToPrint = '' +
    '<style >' +
    'body {' +
    'font-family: arial, sans-serif ;' +
    'font-size: 12px ;' +
    '}' +

    'header-cert{' +
    'text-align: center;' +
    'text-decoration: underline;' +
    '}' +

    '</style>';

  htmlToPrint += divToPrint.outerHTML;
  newWin = window.open("");
  newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
  newWin.print();
  newWin.close();
}
```

```html
<div id="printme">
  <div class="border">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cliniclogo" style="background-image: url()">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <div class="header-cert">
          <p class="certheader"></p>
          <p class="certheader" id="clinic_name"></p>
          <p class="certheader"><label id="clinic_address"></label>, &nbsp; <label id="city_name"></label> </p>
          <p class="certheader"><label id="province_name"></label>, &nbsp; <label id="zipcode"></label> </p>
        </div>
        <!-- header-cert -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <p class="medcert">MEDICAL CERTIFICATE</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-10">
        <p>Date: <u><?php echo "".date(' M j, Y'); ?></u></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p class="certmarg">To Whom It May Concern:</p>
      </div>
      <!-- col-md-4 -->
    </div>
    <!-- row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="startindent">THIS IS TO CERTIFY that &nbsp; <label id="cert_name"></label> &nbsp; of &nbsp; <label id="cert_address"></label> &nbsp; was examined and treated at the &nbsp; <label id="cert_clinic_name"></label> &nbsp; on <label id="cert_check_up_date"></label>          with the following diagnosis: &nbsp; <label id="cert_diagnosis"></label> &nbsp; and would need medical attention for &nbsp; <label id="cert_physician"></label> &nbsp; days barring complication.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- row -->
    <div class="signatory">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-10">
          <u><p id="cert_physician_signatory"><label id="cert_physician_sig"></label>, M.D.</p></u>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- signatory -->
  </div>
  <!-- printme -->
```

why does it not makes my `header-cert` centered in printing? it didn't follow the css that i've put.

Comment: `header-cert` is not an `html` element. Which element are you trying to select?

Comment: @guest271314 <div class="header-cert"> its a class. i want that class to be centered all the text

Comment: The selector at `css` should be `.header-cert`.

Comment: @guest271314 can you give me an example sir? or can you answer? a printing div with classes inside, and something like in my javascript code, i want to follow with that css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed `.` in `header-cert`, so use `.header-cert`.

```js
function printDiv() {
        var divToPrint = document.getElementById('printme');
        var htmlToPrint = '' +
        '<style rel="text/stylesheet">' +
        'body {' +
            'font-family: arial, sans-serif ;' +
            'font-size: 12px ;' +
            '}' +

        '.header-cert{' +
            
            'text-align: center;' +
            'text-decoration: underline;' +
            '}' +

        '</style>';

        htmlToPrint += divToPrint.outerHTML;
        //newWin = window.open("");
        newWin = window;
        newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
}

document.getElementById('printBtn').addEventListener('click', function(){

  printDiv();
})
```

```html
<div id="printme">
                  <div class="border">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cliniclogo" style="background-image: url()">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                          <div class="header-cert">
                          <p class="certheader">Cerheader title</p>
                          <p class="certheader" id="clinic_name"></p>
                          <p class="certheader"><label id="clinic_address"></label>, &nbsp; <label id="city_name"></label> </p>
                          <p class="certheader"><label id="province_name"></label>, &nbsp; <label id="zipcode"></label> </p>
                          </div><!-- header-cert -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                          <p class="medcert">MEDICAL CERTIFICATE</p>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- row -->
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-10">
                        <p>Date: <u><?php echo "".date(' M j, Y'); ?></u></p>
                      </div>
                    </div><!-- row -->
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <p class="certmarg">To Whom It May Concern:</p>
                      </div><!-- col-md-4 -->
                    </div><!-- row -->
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p class="startindent">THIS IS TO CERTIFY that &nbsp; <label id="cert_name"></label> &nbsp; of &nbsp; <label id="cert_address"></label>
                         &nbsp; was examined and treated at the &nbsp; <label id="cert_clinic_name"></label> &nbsp; on <label id="cert_check_up_date"></label>
                        with the following diagnosis: &nbsp; <label id="cert_diagnosis"></label> &nbsp; and would need medical attention for 
                        &nbsp; <label id="cert_physician"></label> &nbsp; days barring complication.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div><!-- row -->
                    <div class="signatory">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-10">
                              <u><p id="cert_physician_signatory"><label id="cert_physician_sig"></label>, M.D.</p></u>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- signatory -->
                    
                    
                    <button id="printBtn">Print<button>
```

Comment: lol i just forgot "." .. btw , thanks.. how can i change this to landscape printing instead of portrait ?